# Occasional NPE when accessing fragment's view

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-view, android-lifecycle

I occasionally get `NullPointerException` when entering fragment. It happens when the app was in the background for a long time and then I open it and swipe to this fragment.

```
public class SummaryFragment extends Fragment implements FragmentLifecycle {

    private static final String TAG = "DTAG";
    private DateFormat dateFormatName;
    private Preference prefs;
    private List<String> monthList;
    private TextView totalTimeFullTv;
    private TextView totalTimeNetTv;
    private TextView averageTimeTv;
    private TextView overUnderTv;
    private TextView minTimeTv;
    private TextView maxTimeTv;
    private TextView vacationsTv;
    private TextView sickTv;
    private TextView headlineTv;
    private TextView overUnderTvH;
    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public SummaryFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    public static SummaryFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        SummaryFragment fragment = new SummaryFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View RootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_summary, container, false);

        dateFormatName = new SimpleDateFormat(getResources().getString(R.string.month_text));
        monthList = Arrays.asList(new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths());
        prefs = new Preference(GeneralAdapter.getContext());


        totalTimeFullTv = RootView.findViewById(R.id.textView_sum_ttf);
        totalTimeNetTv = RootView.findViewById(R.id.textView_sum_ttn);
        averageTimeTv = RootView.findViewById(R.id.textView_sum_av);
        overUnderTv = RootView.findViewById(R.id.textView_sum_ou);
        overUnderTvH = RootView.findViewById(R.id.textView_sum_ou_h);


        minTimeTv = RootView.findViewById(R.id.textView_sum_min);
        maxTimeTv = RootView.findViewById(R.id.textView_sum_max);
        vacationsTv = RootView.findViewById(R.id.textView_sum_vac);
        sickTv = RootView.findViewById(R.id.textView_sum_sick);
        headlineTv= RootView.findViewById(R.id.textView_sum_headline);

        return RootView;
    }

    private void refreshData() {

        if (prefs == null)
        {
            prefs = new Preference(GeneralAdapter.getContext());
        }

        String month = prefs.getString(Preference.CURRENT_MONTH);

        MonthData monthData = Calculators.CalculateLocalData(MainActivity.db.getAllDays(month));

        totalTimeFullTv.setText(monthData.getTotalTimeFull()); //Crash here
        totalTimeNetTv.setText(monthData.getTotalTimeNet());
        averageTimeTv.setText(monthData.getAverageTime());
        overUnderTv.setText(monthData.getOverUnder());
        if (monthData.getOverUnderFloat()<0)
        {
            overUnderTvH.setText(R.string.sum_over_time_neg);
            overUnderTv.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(GeneralAdapter.getContext(),R.color.negative_color));
        }
        else
        {
            overUnderTvH.setText(R.string.sum_over_time_pos);
            overUnderTv.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(GeneralAdapter.getContext(),R.color.positive_color));
        }

        minTimeTv.setText(monthData.getMinTime());
        maxTimeTv.setText(monthData.getMaxTime());
        vacationsTv.setText(""+monthData.getVacations());
        sickTv.setText(""+monthData.getSick());
        headlineTv.setText(month);
    }

    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachFragment(Fragment childFragment) {
        super.onAttachFragment(childFragment);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPauseFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onResumeFragment()
    {
        refreshData();
    }


    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

**MainActivity viewPager:**

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            int currentPosition = 0;

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                FragmentLifecycle fragmentToHide = (FragmentLifecycle) adapter.getItem(currentPosition);
                fragmentToHide.onPauseFragment();

                FragmentLifecycle fragmentToShow = (FragmentLifecycle) adapter.getItem(position);
                fragmentToShow.onResumeFragment(); //Crash start

                currentPosition = position;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
```

**Log:**

```
                                            E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: michlind.com.workcalendar, PID: 25038
                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                   at michlind.com.workcalendar.mainfragments.SummaryFragment.refreshData(SummaryFragment.java:99)
                                                   at michlind.com.workcalendar.mainfragments.SummaryFragment.onResumeFragment(SummaryFragment.java:147)
                                                   at michlind.com.workcalendar.activities.MainActivity.onPageSelected(MainActivity.java:84)
                                                   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.dispatchOnPageSelected(ViewPager.java:1941)
                                                   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.scrollToItem(ViewPager.java:680)
                                                   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:664)
                                                   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onTouchEvent(ViewPager.java:2257)
                                                   at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:11776)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2962)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2643)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)
                                                   at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:448)
                                                   at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1829)
                                                   at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3307)
                                                   at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:68)
                                                   at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:410)
                                                   at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:12015)
                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4795)
                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4609)
                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4147)
                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4200)
                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4166)
                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4293)
                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4174)
                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4350)
                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4147)
                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4200)
                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4166)
                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4174)
                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4147)
                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6661)
                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6635)
                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6596)
                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6764)
                                                   at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:186)
                                                   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
                                                   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:325)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:142)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
```

**UPDATE:**

I eventually used:

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {

    Fragment fragment = adapter.getFragment(position);
    if (fragment != null) {
        fragment.onResume();
    }
}
```

At my MainActivity, and used onResume() at each fragment. And this solution for the adapter:
http://thedeveloperworldisyours.com/android/update-fragment-viewpager/

Comment: why are you not casting `totalTimeFullTv` as TextView

Comment: @vm345 if OP uses appcompat, casting isn't needed. A new update in a later version of Android was adapted by appcompat into fragments and activities, making casting redundant when using the appcompat imports

Comment: Did you try to delay by 50-100 ms inside your onResumeFragment () ?

Comment: Tried with 10, seems to get much better, but still crashed some times. Noe trying with 500! But it not seems the right solution. Just a workaround.

Comment: You need to put your `refreshData()` in `onActivityCreated()` method, to avoid this kind of situations. Your views are not created.

Comment: Should your "Update" not better be a distinct *answer* instead of being added to the *question*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, that you are trying to access views too early: view hierarchy is not created at that point yet.

If you post an event, that would take place on the next frame, you are guaranteed, that view hierarchy would be already setup:

```
@Override
public void onResumeFragment() {
    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            refreshData();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It reduced crashes dramatically, but they still happen once in a while...

Comment: Instead of `post()`, try `postDelayed()` with some small value, e.g 10ms.

Comment: Still happening sometimes. Currently trying with 500ms! But it not seems the right coding solution. In my logs I can see that OnCreate happens before onResumeFragment for sure. An the the view in OnCreate is not null. This is very weird.

Comment: Is the exception message exactly the same?

Comment: Yes, the same thing happens

Comment: This is not the recommended solution. This is basically hoping that the page was laid out after a set amount of milliseconds. This delay might be 'too soon' in some cases, as well as 'unnecessarily late' for other cases.

Comment: This is not good solution, why you don't use native onResume() method? You don't have to call it by yourself Android will call it for you and only when view will be created, this answer should not be accepted as correct

Comment: @AbdulWasae, `This is basically hoping that the page was laid out after a set amount of milliseconds` there is nothing in the answer itself, that relies on some milliseconds, so your statement is invalid.

Comment: @JardaHavelik, `This is not good solution` please clarify why. `why you don't use native onResume() method?` Because `onResume` will be called anytime user minimizes app using home button and opens app from recents app list, whereas OP wants to perform an action when user selects a page. `this answer should not be accepted as correct` Please clarify your opinion.

Comment: @azizbekian this solution is basically hoping that view will be created in certain amout of time, this is not universal solution for all devices -
 will crash anyway in some cases. Another way to do so (if you dont like usage of native onResume) is to use some kind of event bus (send event to all correctly subscribed fragments). Correctly subscribead means that it is subscribed f.e. in onViewCreated() method and unsubscribed in odDestroyView() method

Comment: @JardaHavelik, `this solution is basically hoping that view will be created in certain amout of time` not exactly, this solution is hoping that view will be created **on the next frame**, which by the design of the framework, should have been done by that time. Can you please provide a counterargument for my upper-mentioned statement? `if you dont like usage of native onResume` Likeliness does not matter. I claim, that `onResume()` approach is faulty and I clarify why, I do **not** just tell *"I don't like that approach"*.

Comment: @JardaHavelik `Correctly subscribead means that it is subscribed f.e. in onViewCreated()` At the point when `onPageSelected()` is called you do not **yet** have `Fragment#onViewCreated()` called, which means you will miss the event. You may claim, that then **sticky** subscription should be used, which would mean, that you also should take care of not regarding event after orientation change happens, because `onViewCreated()` will be called again and event would be received again.

Comment: @JardaHavelik  Also, usage of event bus is not a decision which easily can be applied to any project due to different opinions concerning the technique.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem when I had implemented custom life cycles for ViewPager. I think you are using FragmentStatePagerAdapter to populate fragments with ViewPager. As we know FragmentStatePagerAdapter destroys all the fragments when they lose focus. We need to provide same object for every page using **singleton pattern**.

In **your code**, Fragment creation can be like below for singleton pattern.

```
private SummaryFragment mInstance;

private SummaryFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

public static SummaryFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        if(mInstance == null)
        mInstance = new SummaryFragment();
        return mInstance;
    }
```

Doing this has solved my problem. If this does not work for you? Can you share your PagerAdapter class.

Answer (score 0):

`onResumeFragment()` is getting invoked before the creation of all the views of this fragment.
Try recreating newInstance first and then invoke `onResumeFragment` of `FragmentLifeCycle` interface in your Activity.

Answer (score 0):

`ViewPager` keeps several items on either side attached (i.e. fragments resumed), however `FragmentPagerAdapter` uses `Fragment.setUserVisibleHint` to indicate, which item is current. Leverage that instead.

Here's what to do to leverage user visible hint:

1. Remove the `OnPageChangeListener`.
2. Ditch the `FragmentLifecycle` interface.
3. Set your fragment like so:

(in Kotlin, but you'll get the gist)

```
override fun setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser: Boolean) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser)

    if (isVisibleToUser && isResumed) {
        // Do stuff.
    }
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()

    if (userVisibleHint) {
        // Do the same stuff.
    }
}
```

#### More info

`FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem` is a factory method. It's *always* supposed to return you a new instance of a fragment. If you tried to cache them, remove the cache (1) and don't use `getItem` yourself (2).

1. Code that sometimes crashes and sometimes doesn't is a b**** to debug. This can be caused by reusing fragments when you're not supposed to.
2. A new fragment instance is not attached, has no reason to create views and will be garbage collected once you leave `onPageSelected`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using OnPageChangeListener incorrectly. This is not a safe way to control view lifecycle events. You need to use PagerAdapter in conjunction with ViewPager and override its instantiateItem / destroyItem callbacks.

See this example: http://android-er.blogspot.com/2014/04/example-of-viewpager-with-custom.html

PagerAdapter is to ViewPager what ListAdapter is to ListView, you need both to make your system work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use `onViewCreated()` callback method of fragment to update your data that way you are sure that all your views are laid out perfectly.

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   refreshData();

}
```

Using `Handler` can still be risky as you can't be sure the view are inflated or not.

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEM**

The lifecycle of a `Fragment` is independent. You cannot be sure that when an `onPageSelected()` gets registered, that fragment has already been laid out. It's is an asynchronous event. So you cannot rely on this callback.

But on the other hand, you cannot also rely only on the `onResume()`, since in a ViewPager, the pages adjacent to the currently visible page are preloaded.

**SOLUTION**

Principally you will need to `refreshData()` when the fragment is visible to user and actively running. The definition of [onResume()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onResume()) says the same:

> Called when the fragment is visible to the user and actively running. (...)

So simply call `refreshData()` in the `onResume()` of your fragment, and don't worry if you notice this getting called while the ViewPager wasn't really showing this page.

Comment: I eventually used similar solution, but onResume() is super from the activity running the fragment, and not triggered each time the view is shown.

Comment: It is not triggered each time the view is shown because it had already been resumed when your viewPager was showing an adjacent page. This is normal.

Comment: Yes, but I want to refresh view each time fragment is shown

Comment: Think of it like this. For a viewPager, there are 3 visible fragments at all times: The current one, the immediate left one, the immediate right one. 
However, if you still want to do it in a brute force manner, you can put this check in `refreshData`: `if (this.isVisible) { // continue function }`

Comment: @JardaHavelik this does not fulfill the use case, that OP has, because `onResume()` will be called any time user minimizes app using home button and navigates back to app, whereas OP needs to `refreshData()` only when page gets selected. Thus, this cannot be considered as a valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

Like most people said you need to make sure your fragment is active and visible to the user. i had a similar problem. I used onHiddenChanged to decided when to reload data.

```
@Override
public void onHiddenChanged(boolean hidden) {
    super.onHiddenChanged(hidden);
    if (!hidden) {
        refreshData();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> You should inflate your layout in `onCreateView` but shouldn't initialize other views using `findViewById` in `onCreateView`.

here is a code from the FragmentManager

```
  // This calls onCreateView()
f.mView = f.performCreateView(f.getLayoutInflater(f.mSavedFragmentState), null, f.mSavedFragmentState);

// Null check avoids possible NPEs in onViewCreated
// It's also safe to call getView() during or after onViewCreated()
if (f.mView != null) {
    f.mView.setSaveFromParentEnabled(false);
    if (f.mHidden) f.mView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    f.onViewCreated(f.mView, f.mSavedFragmentState);
}
```

It's better to do any assignment of subviews to fields in `onViewCreated`. This is because the framework does an automatic null check for you to ensure that your Fragment's view hierarchy has been created and inflated (if using an XML layout file) properly.

once the view is created then initialize your views.

Comment: These two methods are called immediately after each other and `getView()` is never called during `onCreateView()`. It crashes elsewhere.

Answer (score -1):

Add this check in refreshData() method:

```
if (isAdded() && getActivity() != null)
```